# When grounding conductors in electrostatic problems, is the reference point of electric potential defined at infinity or the ground?

Tags: electrostatics

I am confused about the meaning of 'grounding' in electrostatics. My textbook claims that any grounded conductor has zero electric potential, but it seems to me this claim can have two different meanings:

1. It is zero as the new reference point, which means 'grounding' is actually just a way to define a new reference point for the potential in the problem.
2. Infinity is still the reference point but any grounded conductor has zero potential in reference to infinity.

If it is the latter, how can this be proven? Why is it not possible to arrange distribution of charges around the grounded conductor in such a way that the work done by taking a unit charge from infinity to the conductor is not zero?

Comment: Cross-posted. (You're not supposed to do that.) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475176/when-grounding-conductors-in-electrostatic-problems-is-the-reference-point-of-e  Better on electronics, and it will almost surely be a duplicate there. (I found the cross-post looking for an answer that I know is already on electronics.)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355695/actual-electric-potential-at-terminals-of-battery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Earth acts as a giant capacitor. The capacitance of a sphere of radius $R$ is:

$$ C = 4 \pi \epsilon R $$

and the voltage on a capacitor is given by $V = Q/C$, so if we put a charge $Q$ on the sphere the voltage at the surface of the sphere is:

$$ V = \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon R} $$

For the Earth the radius $R \approx 6371000$ metres so $4 \pi \epsilon R \approx 0.7$ millicoulombs per volt. Unless you put a large charge on the Earth its voltage remains so low as to be effectively zero. This potential is the same as the zero that we take at infinity in electrostatics since it's the potential relative to infinity.

So the Earth acts like a sink or source for charge in the sense that for any sane amount of charge the charge can flow onto or off of the Earth without changing the Earth's potential from zero.

Comment: Isn't the capacitance $$ C = 4 \pi \epsilon R $$

Comment: @SunLight oops, yes, thanks. I have no idea where the 62 came from.

Comment: @JohnRennie Isn't 0.7 millicoulombs a small charge (considering so many people use earth for ground)? And this small charge changes the potential by 1 volt. This is not good in my opinion.